# Getting distance to be 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, distance, pythagorean

I want this div to go from point A to point B and vice-versa. Problem is the `dist` variable (distance) never gets to 0, it is usually either 1 or -1 (or some other range of values), which results in the div getting stuck and not going anywhere. In my complete code, point A and B positions are randomized every time I open the page.

The example below is reproducing the problem. **To see it working as intended set** `#pointA { top: 5px; left: 5px; }` | `#pointB { top: 5px; left: 105px; }`

```js
var score = 0, points = 0, boxMode = 0, speed, speedX, speedY, angleRadians,
distX, distY, dist;

var destinationX = $("#pointB").position().left;
var destinationY = $("#pointB").position().top;

var pointAPos = $("#pointA").position();
var pointAx = pointAPos.left;
var pointAy = pointAPos.top;

var pointBPos = $("#pointB").position();
var pointBx = pointBPos.left;
var pointBy = pointBPos.top;

var boxPos = $('#box').position();
var boxX = pointAx;
var boxY = pointAy;
 
function calculateDistance(x, y) {
  distX = boxX - x;
  distY = boxY - y;
  dist = Math.sqrt((distX*distX)+(distY*distY));
}

function boxMove() {
  angleRadians = Math.atan2(-distX, -distY);
  speed = 2;
  speedX = speed * Math.sin(angleRadians);
  speedY = speed * Math.cos(angleRadians);
 
  document.getElementById("box").style.left = boxX + "px";
  document.getElementById("box").style.top = boxY + "px";
 
  boxX += speedX;
  boxY += speedY;
}

function boxAI() {
  calculateDistance(destinationX, destinationY);
  if (!dist == 0) {
    boxMove();
  } else {
    if (boxMode == 0) {
   points += 1;
   if (points == 50) {
     // change destination to point A
  destinationX = pointAx;
  destinationY = pointAy;
  boxMode = 1;
   }
 } else {
   // change destination to point B
   destinationX = pointBx;
   destinationY = pointBy;
      score += points;
      points = 0;
   boxMode = 0;
 }
  }
}
function mainLoop() {
  boxAI();
  $("#debug").html(points + " " + score + " " + boxMode);
  requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}

requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
```

```css
#levelWrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  top: 2px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
   
#pointA {
  position: absolute;
  background: beige;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  top: 3px;
  left: 50px;
  margin: auto;
}
   
#pointB {
  position: absolute;
  background: beige;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  top: 45px;
  left: 195px;
  margin: auto;
}
   
#box {
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  height: 5px;
  width: 5px;
}

#debug {
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  width: 250px;
  height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="debug"></div>

<div id="levelWrapper">
<div id="pointA">A</div>
<div id="pointB">B</div>
<div id="box"></div>
</div>
  
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="woods_2.js"></script>
  
</body>
```

Comment: NB: a `sqrt()` can never be negative, so you don't need that `if` after it.

Comment: Can you create a stacksnippets to demonstrate issue?

Comment: @guest271314 done

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In JavaScript the `!` operator has precedence over the `==`, so `if (dist != 0)` would already be an improvement.

But as you use a `speed` variable which determines the difference between two consecutive measurements of the distance, you should make your test accordingly, and see if the distance is *one step* removed from zero:

```
if (dist >= speed)
```

Here is your code with some changes:

```js
var score = 0, points = 0, boxMode = 0, speed, speedX, speedY, angleRadians,
distX, distY, dist;

var destinationX = $("#pointB").position().left;
var destinationY = $("#pointB").position().top;

var pointAPos = $("#pointA").position();
var pointAx = pointAPos.left;
var pointAy = pointAPos.top;

var pointBPos = $("#pointB").position();
var pointBx = pointBPos.left;
var pointBy = pointBPos.top;

var boxPos = $('#box').position();
var boxX = pointAx;
var boxY = pointAy;
var speed = 2; // make speed visible to other functions

function calculateDistance(x, y) {
    distX = boxX - x;
    distY = boxY - y;
    dist = Math.sqrt((distX*distX)+(distY*distY));
}

function boxMove() {
    angleRadians = Math.atan2(-distX, -distY);
    speedX = speed * Math.sin(angleRadians);
    speedY = speed * Math.cos(angleRadians);

    document.getElementById("box").style.left = boxX + "px";
    document.getElementById("box").style.top = boxY + "px";

    boxX += speedX;
    boxY += speedY;
}

function boxAI() {
    calculateDistance(destinationX, destinationY);
    // As the distance makes jumps of <speed> units,
    // check whether it is within one step of the target
    if (dist >= speed) {
        boxMove();
    } else {
        score++; // Not sure what score should be measuring
        if (boxMode == 0) {
            // Change destination to point A
            destinationX = pointAx;
            destinationY = pointAy;
            boxMode = 1;
        } else {
            // Change destination to point B
            destinationX = pointBx;
            destinationY = pointBy;
            boxMode = 0;
        }
    }
}

function mainLoop() {
    boxAI();
    $("#debug").html(points + " " + score + " " + boxMode);
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}

requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
```

```css
#levelWrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  top: 2px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
            
#pointA {
  position: absolute;
  background: beige;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  top: 3px;
  left: 50px;
  margin: auto;
}
            
#pointB {
  position: absolute;
  background: beige;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  top: 45px;
  left: 195px;
  margin: auto;
}
            
#box {
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  height: 5px;
  width: 5px;
}

#debug {
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  width: 250px;
  height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="debug"></div>

<div id="levelWrapper">
<div id="pointA">A</div>
<div id="pointB">B</div>
<div id="box"></div>
</div>
```

I did not understand what you wanted to do with *score* and *points*, so you will need to modify the code in that respect. For now I removed the changes to the *points* variable, and only increased *score* with every bounce.

Comment: It is indeed important to show your code. Now I see what your problem is. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Don't worry, points and score were unnecessary for my problem I guess, it was just to illustrate I wanted the box to do something in B and take time there before going back // it really doesn't matter for the problem I posted in the first post actually